# /dev/v4l-subdev0 device node is not created

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, v4l2

I working on interfacing own camera sensor with iMX8mm processor using Linux kernel 5.4. I have written the camera driver for it and probe is successfully as a video sub-device. But /dev/v4l-subdev0 is not created.

I have following these links -

- https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=V4L2_-_Custom_Subdev_IOCTLs
- https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/How-to-create-v4l2-subdevice/m-p/891590#M134802

I am trying to create a this device node to enable setting register values from user-space. Any other way I can set register values ?

Can someone please comment ?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the official Linux kernel documentation?

Comment: I did follow this link
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/media/kapi/v4l2-subdev.html
Along with some reference codes form other similar sensor drivers